# How to pass CONFIG_BUILD_DOCSRC=n to genkernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, gentoo

I need a Gentoo 13 machine to test some software on the platform. I'm not a Gentoo regular, so I'm suffering their install procedures. I'm at [Configuring the Linux kernel](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Kernel), and it failed with:

```
(chroot) #  genkernel all
...

Documentation/vDSO/parse_vdso.o: In function `elf_hash':
parse_vdso.c:(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
Documentation/vDSO/parse_vdso.o: In function `vdso_init_from_sysinfo_ehdr':
parse_vdso.c:(.text+0x445): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
Documentation/vDSO/parse_vdso.o: In function `vdso_match_version':
parse_vdso.c:(.text+0x545): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
Documentation/vDSO/parse_vdso.o: In function `vdso_sym':
parse_vdso.c:(.text+0x6fa): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
Documentation/vDSO/parse_vdso.o: In function `vdso_init_from_auxv':
parse_vdso.c:(.text+0x7b5): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
```

This is a somewhat known issue, and the fix is to set `CONFIG_BUILD_DOCSRC=n` (see [here](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7850564.html?sid=f9b005231a755f7c79783a3f5ab41f79) and [here](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7745434.html#7745434)).

I found `CONFIG_BUILD_DOCSRC` in two configuration files, but both are marked as *autogenerated, do not edit*. So I'm trying to pass `CONFIG_BUILD_DOCSRC=n` to `genkernel`. I've been through the `genkernel(8)` man pages but I did not see how to pass an arbitrary setting like `CONFIG_BUILD_DOCSRC=n` (it may be there and I could have missed it).

I tried `genkernel all CONFIG_BUILD_DOCSRC=n`, but that resulted in an ***`error: unknown option...`***.

How do I pass `CONFIG_BUILD_DOCSRC=n` to `genkernel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to post an answer, but I'm not sure if its correct because I'm not really qualified to build kernels...

The following can be added to `/etc/genkernel.conf`:

```
CONFIG_BUILD_DOCSRC="n"
```

It looks like it produces the expected results:

```
(chroot) Gentoo-2012 / # genkernel all
* Gentoo Linux Genkernel; Version 3.4.52.3
* Running with options: all

* Using genkernel.conf from /etc/genkernel.conf
* Sourcing arch-specific config.sh from /usr/share/genkernel/arch/x86_64/config.sh ..
* Sourcing arch-specific modules_load from /usr/share/genkernel/arch/x86_64/modules_load ..

* Linux Kernel 4.1.15-gentoo-r1 for x86_64...
* .. with config file /usr/share/genkernel/arch/x86_64/generated-config
* kernel: Using config from /usr/share/genkernel/arch/x86_64/generated-config
*         Previous config backed up to .config--2016-03-14--02-25-26.bak
* kernel: >> Running mrproper...
*         >> Running oldconfig...
* kernel: >> Cleaning...
*         >> Compiling 4.1.15-gentoo-r1 bzImage...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should of course configure the kernel first using `make menuconfig` or `make nconfig` (I personally prefer the latter)

Inside menuconfig/nconfig, search for "BUILD_DOCSRC", and unselect it.